# Why settings.gradle file is not used when -b is specified?

Tags: build, gradle

From [Gradle User Guide](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_gradle_command_line.html) we can read that

```
You can use the -b option to select another build file. If you use -b option then settings.gradle file is not used.
```

So lets have:

```
-Example      #Project root
 --src
   --main
   --test
 --build.gradle
 --second.gradle #Second build script
 --settings.gradle
```

---

What is the purpose of this? If I want to try something different with my multiproject build I create another script file - second.gradle and put it in the same directory. But want old settings.gradle file to include my subprojects.

If I execute my gradle comands when I am in the root directory of *Example* project for ex:

```
gradle  -b second.gradle clean build
```

Why Gradle does not use settings.gradle file? To protect itself when specified build file is not in the same dir, because Gradle will looks for settings.gradle  in the direcotry of build.gradle file and after that in the parent directory. But they can empty or can be from another project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-b` allows to pass a different build script for a single-project build. It is not meant to be used for multi-project builds, where `settings.gradle` alone determines where build scripts are located.