# When -b is specified settings.gradle is still used, even if it shouldn't. Why?

Tags: gradle

Based on the documentation:

> If you use -b option then settings.gradle file is not used.

But I created this simple project:

```
.
├── anotherBuild.gradle
├── build.gradle
└── settings.gradle
```

With `build.gradle` containing:

```
task taskA{
    doLast{
        println "taskA from build.gradle"
    }
}
```

`anotherBuild.gradle` containing:

```
task taskA{
    doLast{
        println "taskA from anotherBuild.gradle"
    }
}
```

and `settings.gradle` containing:

```
println "From settings.gradle, executed during initialization phase"
```

When I run:

```
gradle -q -b anotherBuild.gradle taskA
```

I can see that gradle prints "From settings.gradle, executed during initialization phase" anyway. Why that?
Shouldn't the `settings.gradle` be ignored when using `-b`?

Comment: You're right, sorry! Which version are you running?

Comment: That's fine :) I'm using Gradle 4.0.

Comment: Hmm.. I've prepared an example that reproduces the problem, strange. This may be of your interest: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-set-multiproject-with-customized-build-script-b/7440/9

Comment: Even in this case the problem is the opposite. I'm not using a multiproject build and therefore I can use ```-b```, and it works because I'm reading from the build file passed as parameter.

Comment: If you have a `settings.gradle` file in you project it becomes a multiproject build.

Comment: You are right, sorry. But still this doesn't explain why the ```settings.gradle```` file is not ignored.

Comment: Yes, exactly. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21337035/542270 - the question with which I closed yours. Peter states that `-b` doesn't work with multi-project builds at all.

Comment: That means that "If you use -b option then settings.gradle file is not used." is misleading. ```-b``` doesn't make ```settings.gradle``` not used. Simply you shouldn't use ```-b``` and ```settings.gradle``` together because it won't work as expected.

Comment: Yes, it seems that this is finally the point.

Comment: @Opal having a `settings.gradle` doesn't make your build a multi-project build. Including a second project in `settings.gradle` makes the build a multi-project build. You e. g. even need a `settings.gradle` in a single-project build if you want to explicitly name the root project or set a plugin repository and some other stuff. Actually in my opinion the root project name should always be set explicitly to not have it derived from the root project directory name and thus there should always be a `settings.gradle` as is generated by the `init` task.

Comment: @Vampire, yes you're right. Actually is use `settings.gradle` in my single module project just for setting the name. IMHO it looks like a bug.

Comment: @Vampire how can we check if it is a bug and eventually report it?
I'm going through the documentation and checking how it is working.

Comment: It definitely is a bug, either a code bug or a doku bug if the docs say `settings.gradle` is ignored if `-b` is used and `settings.gradle` is not actually ignored. You can report it at https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues

Comment: @Vampire Opened this: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/3100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably a bug that the `settings.gradle` is used though `-b` is specified, but `-b` is only meant for quick testing and experimenting anyway.

In my opinion you should always have a `settings.gradle` e. g. to specify the root project name explicitly instead of deriving it from the root project directory name.

What you can do if you really need different build scripts next to each other is to also have different settings scripts which point to the different build scripts and then use `-c` to select the right settings script instead of using `-b`.